# How can I list positive and negative values separately in listview box in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, gui

Here's my AHK script:

```
Gui, Add, Edit, x77 y15 w100 h30 vMyvar gEdit1 ;first edit box, there can be entered any value.
Gui, Add, Edit, x237 y15 w100 h30 vNewvar Disabled, %Newvar% ;second edit box it shows the result by multiplying the first edit box's value by 100.
Gui, Add, Edit, x72 y60 w100 h30 vMyv gEdit2  ;third edit box, there can be entered any value.
Gui, Add, Edit, x242 y60 w100 h30 vNewv Disabled, %Newv% ;fourth edit box it shows the result by multiplying the second edit box's value by 50

Gui, Add, Edit, x242 y110 w100 h30 vTotal Disabled  ;this edit box shows the total of %Newvar% and %Newv% i.e. second edit box and fourth edit box.

Gui, Add, ListView, x282 y200 w100 h300 , 100|50|total ;listview box which lists the values of first edit box and third edit box
Gui, Add, Button, x62 y120 w100 h30 gNext, NEXT  ;next botton which when pressed lists the values of first edit box and third edit box and also clears the second edit box and fourth edit box everytime it pressed.

Gui, Show, w473 h373, Untitled GUI
return

Edit1:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
NewVar := Myvar * 100
GuiControl,, Newvar, %Newvar%
gosub, SetTotal
return

Edit2:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
NewV := Myv * 50
GuiControl,, Newv, %Newv%
gosub, SetTotal
return

SetTotal:
Total := 0
if NewVar is number
    Total += NewVar
if Newv is number
    Total += Newv
GuiControl,, Total, %Total%
return

Next:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
LV_Insert(1,, Myvar, Myv, Total)
Newvar := ""
Newv := ""
Total := ""
GuiControl,, Newvar, %Newvar%
GuiControl,, Newv, %Newv%
GuiControl,, Total, %Total%
return
```

I want these controls to be added in this GUI:

```
Gui, Add, ListView, x62 y170 w200 h300 , s no|100|50|total ; this listview box is for negative values and i added s no column also in it which should contain the serial no as the negative values are entered in this box.
Gui, Add, ListView, x282 y170 w200 h300 , s no|100|50|total ; same listview box for positive values.
Gui, Add, Text, x402 y20 w130 h20 , no of negative values 
Gui, Add, Text, x402 y50 w130 h20 , total of negative value
Gui, Add, Edit, x542 y20 w100 h20 , ;in this edit box i want that there should come only the total no of negative values. say there are 10 nagative values in negative listview box then it should contain only no 10
Gui, Add, Edit, x542 y50 w100 h20 , ; in this edit box i want that it should contain the total of all the negative values i.e. if the total of all 10 negative value is say 50000 then it should contain 50000.
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

as i want two listview boxes and out of them first should list the positive values and another should list negative values, as the total (as the third edit box shows the total of %Newvar% and %Newv%) is positive then it should be listed in positive value listview box and the total is negative then it should be listed in negative listview box. Moreover there should be s no (serial no) column also for both the negative and positive listview boxes.
i made two edit boxes more in which i want the number of negative values should come and in another edit box there should come the total of all negative values.

Comment: What is the issue? Where is your code going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the flow of your program is as follows:

- In GUI 1, the user enters items, hits next and they get added to a table
- In GUI 2, the items in GUI 1 table get sorted into Table A (Positives) and Table B (Negatives)

What it sounds like you may need to do is make the following adjustments:

- For GUI1, add another button to proceed to GUI2.  We'll call this a Proceed button.
- When the Proceed button is pressed...
- Hide GUI1
- Loop through all the values in your finalized GUI1 table
- For each value, add it to one of the GUI2 tables (or a variable that will get written to that table) based on whether it is negative or positive
- After all of the numbers are processed into their corresponding tables, show GUI2
- You will need to refactor the code above to make GUI2 into the second GUI (see help files as needed for using more than one GUI--basically you just have to add the GUI number in front of all of the commands